# Adding custom pop up in Magento Admin page

Tags: magento2, adminhtml

Is that possible to create something like form and selection box in this popup?

right now I'm using this code to add custom button in my Plugin class, but I don't know how to add the customizable popup in the button

```
public function beforeSetLayout(\Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View $view)
{
   $message = __('Are you sure you want to book Shipper?');

        $view->addButton(
            'book_shipper',
            [
                'label' => __('Book Shipper'),
                'class' => 'book-shipper',
                'onclick' => "confirmSetLocation('{$message}', '{$url}')"
            ]
        );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> **Try this**

```
$this->addButton(
    'delete',
    [
        'label' => __('Delete Location'),
        'onclick' => 'deleteConfirm(' . json_encode(__('Are you sure you want to Delete This Location ?'))
            . ','
            . json_encode($this->getUrl('*/*/delete',['id'=> 12 ]))
            . ')',
        'class' => 'scalable delete',
        'level' => -1
    ]
);
```

Comment: I think your code doesn't have a code to creating a form or selection box isn't it?

Comment: I update the answer please check it.